# How to get response on onError inside Rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit 2.0 in my project with Observable interface and the Result wrapper.
The method:

```
Observable<CompanyModel> companyList(@Query("userAcc") String userAcc,
                                     @Query("password") String password);
```

The code:

```
RetrofitHelper.getCompanyList(userName, password).subscribe(new Observer<CompanyModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("Observable completed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Observable error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(CompanyModel companyModel) {
            List<Company> company = companyModel.getCompany();
            System.out.println("Observable next");
        }
    });
```

I want to get response when the error occurred,but onError return Throwable.
How can I get the response?

Comment: In retrofit 1.9, the throwable was actually a RetrofitError, on which you could get the Body like that: `((RetrofitError) e).getBodyAs(CompanyModel.class)`. Not sure how it works with retrofit 2, but I would start by putting a break point in that  `onError` and checking more closely what exactly is in that throwable

Comment: @njzk2 The throwable may be SocketTimeoutException,JSONException...The question is that I can get a JSONException ,but I can not get the Response, can not see the return  string of JSONObject, can not get the status code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can wrap your model inside Response change the Observer declaration to `Observable<Response<CompanyModel>>` and get the Error `errorBody()`

For another reference you can check [this github issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1218)

Comment: above one is helpful to me. This is also help full https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815515/how-do-i-get-response-body-when-there-is-an-error-when-using-retrofit-2-0-observ